# To find records which have same

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have records in the table as shown in the attached image. All i need to find those records who have same "sortorder" different "packageboxtypeid" w.r.t "CCID". So we need to find those records which have same CCID, same sortorder but different packageboxtypeid. Please help.[image]

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like something like this would work. By using an `INNER JOIN` with `SELECT *`, you can compare the records side-by-side.

```
SELECT *
FROM [Table] A
    INNER JOIN [Table] B
        ON A.CCID = B.CCID
            AND A.SortOrder = B.SortOrder
            AND A.PackageBoxTypeId <> B.PackageBoxTypeId
```

However, if you just need a pure list of the records instead of a side-by-side comparison, you can use a correlated sub-query with `EXISTS` or `IN` as @gmiley points out in the comments. I chose `EXISTS` as an example since I don't know if your `PackageBoxTypeId` has NULL values, but I steer away from `IN` when there are NULL columns.

```
SELECT *
FROM [Table] A
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM [Table]
    WHERE CCID = A.CCID
        AND SortOrder = A.SortOrder
        AND PackageBoxTypeId <> A.PackageBoxTypeId
)
```

Comment: Was just about to post the same thing. I would also include that, along with the `JOIN`, you could use a subquery via `EXISTS` or `IN` to similar effect.

Comment: Agree completely. I chose the `JOIN` so that you can compare the 2 records side by side instead of just a pure list of records that are not matched, but business requirements could dictate either based on what you want to do with it.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table1 t2
   ON t1.CCID = t2.CCID
   AND t1.sortorder = t2.sortorder
   AND t1.packageboxtypeid <> t2.packageboxtypeid
```